# MySQL Update if name already exists but only the price

Tags: mysql

i have a problem and tested a few examples i found on google but nothing works..

That is my code

```
INSERT INTO items (name, price, site, link, imagelink)
                    SELECT * FROM (SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) AS tmp
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT name FROM items WHERE name = %s
                    ) LIMIT 1
```

With that, i never get a duplicate item (by name) in my table

I have the fields: name, price, pricebefore, site, link, imagelink

I want to set the `pricebefore = price` if the name is the same from the new insert and the price is different than the price, that is already in the table

So if i have an item with

```
name = iphone
price = 1000
```

And now get new price for the same named item

i want to set the old price to "pricebefore" and the new price to "price".

ON Duplicate KEY doesnt work or i used it wrong, cause the link is different everytime, cause the session add something to the link everytime. So the INSERT is never the same (cause different links) but its the same item.

That must be checked by the name and if the price is not the same, than update with new price and put the old price to `pricebefore`

So it must be like checking if the name exists already.
If not, than insert like my example. But if it exists, than update the price to the new and the current price to pricebefore

Comment: You need to add a unique index to `name`. Then you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: @Barmar but than it update everytime, also if the price is the same like before... i only want to update, if the price is different and the name is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a unique index to `name` to prevent duplicates. Then you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Do this once:

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD UNIQUE INDEX (name);
```

Then use this to insert:

```
INSERT INTO items (name, price, site, link, imagelink)
VALUES %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    pricebefore = IF(price = VALUES(price), pricebefore, price), 
    price = VALUES(price);
```

The `IF` test will prevent it from changing `pricebefore` if `price` is the same.

Comment: I tried it, but it update than also if the price is the same... i only want to update if the price is different than the current price and the name is the same

Comment: I just added that check

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do want thte [`insert ... on duplicate key` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Consider:

```
insert into items (name, price, site, link, imagelink)
values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) 
on duplicate key update
    pricebefore = case when VALUES(price) != price then price else pricebefore end,
    price = VALUES(price)
```

For this to work as expected, you need a unique constraint (or primary key constraint) on column `name`.

The `case` expression ensures that `pricebefore` is updated only on price change.

Comment: I tried it, but it update than also if the price is the same... i only want to update if the price is different than the current price and the name is the same